# @angular/cli version 1.0.3 how to disableHostCheck

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

After updating my angular/cli. I am getting Invalid host header. I am able to solve it by modify the `Server.js` `file under line no: 402 to if(this.disableHostCheck) return true; to return true` but is there any other way to solve this, as change in the node_module is not good way.

I even tried `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` i still have the same issue.

Note: I am deploy using docker container.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't deploy an application using ng serve... Either use `ng eject`, or build the application using `ng build` and deploy that

Comment: seen this? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/6173? you might have some luck installing angular cli from repo and trying.

Comment: @PierreDuc hi i am new to @angular/cli after doing `ng build` it created folder `dist`, can you guide me how to run that.

Answer (score 6):

just add `--disable-host-check` to you command like so: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`